# Is $\int_0^8 \frac{8}{x(x-8)}dx$ defined?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm given the following integral:

$$\int_0^8 \frac{8}{x(x-8)}dx$$

Which is vertically asymptotic at $x=0$ and $x=8$. My solution is as follows:

$$\int \frac{8}{x(x-8)}dx$$
By partial fraction decomposition:
$$\to \int \frac{1}{8(x-8)}dx - \int\frac{1}{8x}dx$$

Which is, trivially:

$$\frac{1}{8}\Big[ln|x-8| - ln|x|\Big] = g(x)$$

Now, to solve the definite inegral, I break this into two peices:

$$\lim_{b\to 0^+} g(4) - g(b) + \lim_{a\to 8^-} g(a) - g(4)$$

I get $\infty - \infty$. WolframAlpha says "the integral does not converge". So, I answered with UNDEFINED. Apparently, this answer is wrong.

Comment: Wolfram's answer isn't wrong. The integral is indeed divergent.

Comment: You should actually get $-\infty-\infty$, not $\infty-\infty$. The integrand is strictly negative on $(0,8)$, so there's nothing indeterminate in the integral.

Comment: It is a divergent integral.  However, it diverges to $-\infty$.  You will have to consult the definitions in your particular textbook to see what "defined" means for an improper integral in that book.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\lim_{a \to 8^-} g(a) = -\infty$$
and $$\lim_{b \to 0^+} g(b) = +\infty$$
so $$\int_0^8 g'(x)\,dx = \lim_{a \to 8^-} g(a) - \lim_{b \to 0^+} g(b) = -\infty - \infty = -\infty.$$

Also, $$\frac{8}{x(x-8)} = \frac{1}{x-8} - \frac{1}{x}$$ so $g(x)$ should really be defined as $ln|x-8|-ln|x|$. This doesn't make a difference to the result.